# How to insert a character in a string considering a few conditions in python

Tags: python, string

Say I will ask the user to input a string. How can I add a character at the end of every word that ends in "a", "e" or "o"?

For example, from

```
f = "O, awesome people, help me if ya will"
```

I'd have

```
f = "Oh, awesomeh peopleh, help meh if yah will"
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverlfow! You will greatly increase your chances of getting an answer for your question if you include your input, what you have tried, your expected output vs. your actual output and the full stack trace of any errors you receive. You can also read [this guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 5):

Use `re.sub`

```
re.sub(r'(?i)([aeo])\b', r'\1h', s)
```

- `(?i)` helps to do case-insensitive match.
- `([aeo])` captures a,e,o only if it's followed by a word boundary.

**Example:**

```
>>> import re
>>> f = "O, awesome people, help me if ya will"
>>> re.sub(r'(?i)([aeo])\b', r'\1h', f)
'Oh, awesomeh peopleh, help meh if yah will'
```

Comment: @Kasra: with loop and `endswith`